# Super class elements not returned with class in morphia and mongoDB with jersey

Tags: mongodb, jersey, morphia

I have base class as

```
@XmlRootElement
public abstract class BaseDO {

    @Id
    protected ObjectId id;

    /**
     * We'll only provide getters for these attributes, setting is done in @PrePersist.
     */
    protected Date creationDate;
    protected Date lastChange;
```

.....and user class as:

```
@Entity(value = "user", noClassnameStored = true)
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlSeeAlso({BaseDO.class})
public class AtsUser extends BaseDO {

    public static enum UserStatus {
        CREATED, ACTIVE, INACTIVE, DELETED, CLOSED
    }

    @Indexed(unique = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Indexed(unique = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Indexed(unique = false)
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @Embedded
    private List<UserRoleDO> roles = new ArrayList<UserRoleDO>();

    // private String userId; //TODO add this later
    private UserStatus status;

    private String success;
```

.....

the REST API is as follows:

```
@Path("user/validate")
public class AtsUserValidationService {

    private AtsUserDao dao; 
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");



    @GET @Path("/query")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public AtsUser  getUserByEmailn(@QueryParam("email") String email) {

        System.out.println("in getUserByEmailn");
            dao = new AtsUserMongodbDao();
            System.out.println("firstName " + email);
            AtsUser atsUser = dao.getAtsUsersByEmail(email) ;

                return atsUser ;
    }
```

....

The morphia Dao is as follows:

```
@Override
public AtsUser getAtsUsersByEmail(String email) {
    AtsUser atsUser = null;
    if ((email == null) || email.isEmpty()   ) {
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println("getAtsUsersByEmail:" + email);
    Query<AtsUser> query = mongoDatastore.find(AtsUser.class);
    query.field("email").equal(email);
    atsUser = query.get();
    return atsUser;
}
```

.....

When I debug, I see the id field and creationDate fields in the java code, but the JSON does not contain that. Here is what my JSON looks like.

```
{

    "id": null,
    "code": "admin",
    "desc": "admin",
    "email": "admin@aa.com",
    "firstName": "admin",
    "lastName": "admin",
    "password": "admin",
    "status": "CREATED"

}
```

Why my id is null and how can i get elements from base class to show up in the JSON ?

Comment: It really sucks that this type of question goes unanswered... Seemsvkike a basic bug in morphia to me. Did you ever find out how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to annotate the base class with @Entity as well. It worked for me (using morphia 0.109).